# Facing issue when import file and use inside jest.mock

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to export the object from another file and use it inside the jest.mock.

```
jest.mock('@theme/theme-provider', async() => {
        const dummyThemeStyle = await import(
            'app/style/__tests__/themeObjct.json'
        );
    
        return {
            useTheme: () => ({
                themeStyle: {
                    ...dummyThemeStyle,
                },
            }),
        };
    });
```

but it always return **useTheme is not a function** How to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `async/await` for the `factory` function and use `require` to load the module inside the `factory` function. How the factory function be called? see [v29.5.0/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L1000](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/v29.5.0/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.ts#L1000)

```js
if (this._mockFactories.has(moduleID)) {
    // has check above makes this ok
    const module = this._mockFactories.get(moduleID)!();
    mockRegistry.set(moduleID, module);
    return module as T;
}
```

As you can see, the factory function should **not** be an asynchronous function

```js
jest.mock('@theme/theme-provider', () => {
    const dummyThemeStyle = require('app/style/__tests__/themeObjct.json');

    return {
        useTheme: () => ({
            themeStyle: {
                ...dummyThemeStyle,
            },
        }),
    };
});
```